# Need to print function's actual parameter name used while calling

Tags: java, performance, swing, reflection

I want to print function actual parameter name in function.

For reference please refer below code.Here i am trying reflection.

```
class Refrction
{
    public static int a=12;
    public static int b=12;
    public static int c=13;

    public void click(int x)
    {
        Class cls=Refrction.class;
        Field[] fields = cls.getFields();               

        //here i want to print "a" if function actual parameter is "a" while calling the click function
        //here i want to print "b" if function actual parameter is "b" while calling the click function
        //here i want to print "c" if function actual parameter is "c" while calling the click function

    }
}


public class Reflections extends Refrction
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Refrction ab=new Refrction();
        ab.click(a);
        ab.click(b);
        ab.click(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't - the value of `a`, i.e. 12, is passed to `click`, not the variable itself...

Comment: `click(int x, String caller){ }` `ab.click(a, "a");`

Comment: Thanks For the Solution, But as per my requirement i don't have "a" as string for passing as another argument to click.
If it not possible with above code i need to find another work around.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the values of `a`, `b` and `c` never changes (and you can deduce which variable was used as argument by looking at the value) this is not possible. You need to pass more information to the method.

One way would be to do

```
public void click(int x, String identifier) {
    ...
}
```

and call it with

```
ab.click(a, "a");
```

Or, you could wrap the values in a (possibly mutable) object, as follows:

```
class IntWrapper {
    int value;
    public IntWrapper(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and then do

```
public static IntWrapper a = new IntWrapper(11);
```

and

```
public void click(IntWrapper wrapper) {
    if (wrapper == a) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will be useful .